# Is the allocated memory to variable number is on heap or stack?

Tags: c++, stack, heap-memory

I was wonderding if i declear a variable inside a function is it allocated on stack or heap.
Say i have this example .

```cpp
class A{};

void fun() {
    A number;
}
```

wher will be this `number` assign memory i.e on stack or heap because the function is placed inside stack as per knowlede. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any modern compiler presented with this example would not allocate storage for this variable at all, since the variable is unused and has no side-effects.  Even if it's used, one might argue that it could still be neither on the stack nor the heap, if it can be used as a temporary (_e.g._ in registers only).

Comment: @paddy i have updated the question and say it is being used somewhere .

Comment: Some systems don't have a stack or a heap . IMO it's not very productive to think in those terms. If you define a variable inside a code block then it will start existing when execution reaches that line, and stop existing when that code block ends

Comment: Related: [What does it mean for a CPU to support a stack?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61946/what-does-it-mean-for-a-cpu-to-support-a-stack)

Comment: In the code you posted above, assuming that the variable is not optimized away by the compiler and that it actually exists in memory (not only in a CPU register), then it will probably be stored on the stack (assuming your CPU architecture supports storing data on the stack).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you might consider reviewing your subscription to the misconception that every object is either on "the stack" or "the heap".

When you're writing C++, you're not programming a computer; you're describing the behaviour of a program. It's your compiler's job to program the computer and, when it does so, it may or may not choose to use some "stack" or some "heap" on that platform (if said platform even has that!) for some certain task.

In the case of a basic variable like this that's sitting locally inside a function, there's not much need for any memory usage at all; the program's behaviour doesn't depend on that.

That being said, there are general rules we can apply. A more complex object that is "odr-used" (look it up) can require addressability at runtime, and on the mainstream platforms that you're *probably* using, that will indeed involve a stack or a free store ("heap"). Still, if we talk about this property as "automatic storage duration" or "dynamic storage duration" then we can't go wrong.

The direct answer to your question that satisfies the above pedantry, as well as speaking to practical realities on your mainstream computer, is that *there is no dynamic allocation in your function*. Only `malloc` (& friends) and `new` can do that, so only objects created that way (or members of those objects) will live in an area of memory traditionally used by dynamically allocated objects.

Also, it doesn't really matter.